# How to insert php include inside heredoc variable?

Tags: php

I need to have include page inside the php heredoc variable but it doesn't work please help me.

```
$content = <<<EOF
include 'links.php';
EOF;
```

Answer (score 19):

You can do this way:

```
ob_start();
include 'links.php';
$include = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$content = <<<EOF
{$include}
EOF;
```

Comment: You could combine `ob_get_contents` and `ob_end_clean` to `ob_get_clean` :)

Answer (score 3):

Simple: you cannot do it. You can include the file before hand, store it in a variable, then insert it into the file. For example:

```
$links_contents = file_get_contents('links.php');
//$links_contents = eval($links_contents); // if you need to execute PHP inside of the file
$content = <<<EOF
{$links_contents}
EOF;
```

Comment: This is going to include the source of `links.php`, not the executed content.

Comment: Don't `eval` after running `file_get_contents`.  It won't work the way you're expecting.  The reason is that `include` (and hence the `links.php` file) start with the PHP interpreter turned off.  That's why you need `<?php` to turn it on (It starts in non-code context).  `eval` starts with the interpreter turned on (you don't need to prefix php code with `<?php` to get it to work).  So it won't work the way you expect it to.  Not to mention the other evils of `eval`...  So -1 for what boils down to bad advice that won't work...

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by not working? As in contents of 'links.php' isn't in $content? If thats what you want try using output stream redirection (or just read the file).

```
<?php
ob_start();
include 'links.php';
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

echo "contents=[$content]\n";
?>
```

Comment: *sigh* every time I answer a question with no answers, there are 3 or 4 answers before I can finish typing.

Answer (score 1):

Heredoc syntax is made to handle text only. You can't include a file or execute php methods in it.

---

**Resources :**

- [php.net - heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Answer (score 1):

Do not use heredoc at all.
if you need to output your contents - just output it as is, without storing it in the variable.
There can be very limited use of output buffering and I am sure here is not such case.

Just prepare your data and then output it using plain HTML and PHP.
make your pages like this (right from the other recent answer):

news.php:

```
<?
include "config.php"; //connect to database HERE.
$data = getdbdata("SELECT * FROM news where id = %d",$_GET['id']);
$page_title = $data['title'];
$body = nl2br($data['body']);

$tpl_file = "tpl.news.php";
include "template.php";
?>
```

template.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<title><?=$page_title?></title>
</head>
<body>
<? include $tpl_file?>
</body>
```

tpl.news.php

```
<h1><?=$page_title?></h1>
<?=$body?>
<? include "links.php"  /*include your links anywhere you wish*/?>
```